# Automating the functions above so I don't have to write an extra term each time

Tags: python, algorithm, numpy

I was wondering about how could I automate this code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


f = lambda x: x**2 / np.pi**2 * np.sin(x)

a = 2*np.pi
b = 0


midpoint = lambda n: (a/n) * (f(a/(2*n)) + f(a/(2*n)+(a/n)) + f(a/(2*n)+(2*a/n)))

print(midpoint(3))

midpoint = lambda n: (a/n) * (f(a/(2*n)) + f(a/(2*n)+(a/n)) + f(a/(2*n)+(2*a/n)) + f(a/(2*n)+(3*a/n)))

print(midpoint(4))

midpoint = lambda n: (a/n) * (f(a/(2*n)) + f(a/(2*n)+(a/n)) + f(a/(2*n)+(2*a/n)) + f(a/(2*n)+(3*a/n)) + f(a/(2*n)+(4*a/n)))

print(midpoint(5))

midpoint = lambda n: (a/n) * (f(a/(2*n)) + f(a/(2*n)+(a/n)) + f(a/(2*n)+(2*a/n)) + f(a/(2*n)+(3*a/n)) + f(a/(2*n)+(4*a/n)) + f(a/(2*n)+(5*a/n)))

print(midpoint(6))

midpoint = lambda n: (a/n) * (f(a/(2*n)) + f(a/(2*n)+(a/n)) + f(a/(2*n)+(2*a/n)) + f(a/(2*n)+(3*a/n)) + f(a/(2*n)+(4*a/n)) + f(a/(2*n)+(5*a/n)) + f(a/(2*n)+(6*a/n)))

print(midpoint(7))
```

The number of terms in each midpoint corresponds to the value inside the print statement

For example, the first midpoint function has 3 terms, hence evaluated at 3. The second midpoint function has 4 terms, hence evaluated at 4. I need this to go on until 20, without adding an extra term each time.

If everything is done correctly the numbers should be getting closer and closer to the number "-4"

for anyone wondering, this is midpoint integration

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Code:

```
for k in range(3, 20):
    midpoint = lambda n: (a/n) * sum(f(a/(2*n) + (i*a/n)) for i in range(k))
    print(midpoint(k))
```

Explanation:

Obviously, the number of terms simply increments. The somewhat tricky part is adding the additional terms. This bit:

```
sum(f(a/(2*n) + (i*a/n)) for i in range(k))
```

Takes advantage of the fact that the terms being added follow a predictable pattern:

```
term 0 = f(a/(2*n))         = f(a/(2*n) + 0*a/n)
term 1 = f(a/(2*n) + a/n)   = f(a/(2*n) + 1*a/n)
term 2 = f(a/(2*n) + 2*a/n) = f(a/(2*n) + 2*a/n)
```

etc.

All that's changing is the coeffcient in the second half of the sum being passed to `f`, so it's easy to roll the sum up into a loop.

Comment: Your outputs are a bit wrong, while it does approach -4, it starts from more than -4. If doing it manually the first 5 terms starting from 3 are -5.038331567317273
-4.442882938158367
-4.275837328462381
-4.188790204786389
-4.137504221067186

(basically all the outputs should increase not decrease)

Comment: @MickaelAzakov Sorry, had a silly off-by-one error. My code's output now matches yours (tested up through 7).

Answer (score 2):

How about:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def midpoint(f, a, n):
    sum = 0
    for i in range(n):
        sum += f(a/(2*n)+(i*a/n))
    return (a/n) * sum

# Constants
F = lambda x: x**2 / np.pi**2 * np.sin(x)
A = 2*np.pi
B = 0

# Print some examples
for n in range(3, 8):
    print(midpoint(F, A, n))
```

Comment: Your code is correct but doesn't go until 20. Other than that, great job and thank you very much!(I know I can replace 8 with 20 to get the needed code)